# Identity Server 3 as Ws-Fed Identity Provider for SharePoint 2013/2016

Tags: c#, sharepoint, saml, identityserver3, ws-federation

I'm attempting to set up [Thinktecture] Identity Server 3 with SharePoint 2016. However, I'm running into an **infinite loop between SharePoint and Identity Server 3** after the user is authenticated. No errors in the IdServer logs. I would really appreciate if someone would look over my steps below.

## Identity Server 3 Config

I started with the [Self-Host with WS-Federation sample](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/SelfHost%20(InMem%20with%20WS-Fed)), and modified to add a new Relying Party. Identity Server itself is running on a completely separate server from SharePoint, across the Internet, using a public DNS registered hostname:

```
const string url = "https://mydevserver.example.com:44333/core";
using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(url))
{
    Console.WriteLine("\n\nServer listening at {0}. Press enter to stop", url);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

### Relying Party

```
new RelyingParty
{
    Name = "SharePoint 2016 Trial",
    Realm = "urn:idserver:sp16trial",
    Enabled = true,
    ReplyUrl = "https://mysharepointserver.example.com/_trust/",
    TokenType = TokenTypes.Saml11TokenProfile11,
    TokenLifeTime = 1,

    ClaimMappings = new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        { "email", ClaimTypes.Email },
        { "sub", ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier },
        { "name", ClaimTypes.Name },
        { "given_name", ClaimTypes.GivenName },
        { "surname", ClaimTypes.Surname }
   }
}
```

## SharePoint Config

### Metadata and Certificate

I navigate to `https://mydevserver.example.com:44333/core/wsfed/metadata` and save it as an XML file, and I place it onto the SharePoint server temporarily. From the XML file, I extract the public X509 certificate and save it as `temp.cer` file in the same folder as the Powershell script below.

### Powershell Script

```
$realm = "urn:idserver:sp16trial"
$signinurl = "https://mydevserver.example.com:44333/core/wsfed"
$description ="My Test Identity Server 3"

[xml]$fedmdXml = Get-Content metadata.xml
$cert = Get-PfxCertificate -FilePath temp.cer

asnp *sh*
$name = "IdSrv"
New-SPTrustedRootAuthority -Name $name -Certificate $cert | Out-Null

$map1 = New-SPClaimTypeMapping "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress" -IncomingClaimTypeDisplayName "Email" –SameAsIncoming 
$map2 = New-SPClaimTypeMapping "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role" -IncomingClaimTypeDisplayName "Role" -SameAsIncoming
New-SPTrustedIdentityTokenIssuer -Name $name -Description $description -Realm $realm -ImportTrustCertificate $cert -ClaimsMappings $map1,$map2 -SignInUrl $signinurl -IdentifierClaim $map1.InputClaimType
```

I navigate to **SharePoint central administration** and connect the new **trusted provider** to a web application.

In Sharepoint central administration, I authorize the user "bobsmith@example.com" via **Sharepoint User Policy**.

I navigate to `https://mysharepointserver.example.com` and I am redirected to the **Sign In page** `https://mydevserver.example.com:44333/core/login?signin=<guidhere>` as expected.

I sign in as user `bob`, but then the infinite loop is triggered between SharePoint and Identity Server. This is from the IdSvr logs:

## Logs

```
Server listening at https://mydevserver.example.com:44333/core. Press enter to stop
02/26/2017 22:29:53 -08:00 [INF] (IdentityServer3.WsFederation.WsFederationController)
 Start WS-Federation request
02/26/2017 22:29:53 -08:00 [DBG] (IdentityServer3.WsFederation.WsFederationController)
 AbsoluteUri: [https://mydevserver.example.com:44333/core/wsfed?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=urn%3aidserver%3asp16trial&wctx=https%3a%2f%2fmysharepointserver.example.com%2f_layouts%2f15%2fAuthenticate.aspx%3fSource%3d%252F]
02/26/2017 22:29:53 -08:00 [DBG] (IdentityServer3.WsFederation.WsFederationController)
 PublicUri: [https://mydevserver.example.com:44333/core/wsfed?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=urn:idserver:sp16trial&wctx=https:%2f%2fmysharepointserver.example.com%2f_layouts%2f15%2fAuthenticate.aspx%3fSource%3d%252F]
02/26/2017 22:29:53 -08:00 [INF] (IdentityServer3.WsFederation.WsFederationController)
 WsFederation signin request
02/26/2017 22:29:53 -08:00 [INF] (IdentityServer3.WsFederation.Validation.SignInValidator)
 Start WS-Federation signin request validation
02/26/2017 22:29:53 -08:00 [INF] (IdentityServer3.WsFederation.WsFederationController)
 Redirecting to login page
02/26/2017 22:29:53 -08:00 [DBG] (IdentityServer3.Core.Configuration.Hosting.MessageCookie`1)
 Protecting message: {"ReturnUrl":"https://mydevserver.example.com:44333/core/wsfed?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=urn%3aidserver%3asp16trial&wctx=https%3a%2f%2fmysharepointserver.example.com%2f_layouts%2f15%2fAuthenticate.aspx%3fS
ource%3d%252F","AcrValues":[],"Created":636237737932988392}
02/26/2017 22:29:53 -08:00 [INF] (IdentityServer3.Core.Endpoints.AuthenticationController)
 Login page requested
02/26/2017 22:29:53 -08:00 [DBG] (IdentityServer3.Core.Endpoints.AuthenticationController)
 signin message passed to login: {
  "ReturnUrl": "https://mydevserver.example.com:44333/core/wsfed?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=urn%3aidserver%3asp16trial&wctx=https%3a%2f%2fmysharepointserver.example.com%2f_layouts%2f15%2fAuthenticate.aspx%3fSource%3d%252F",
  "ClientId": null,
  "IdP": null,
  "Tenant": null,
  "LoginHint": null,
  "DisplayMode": null,
  "UiLocales": null,
  "AcrValues": [],
  "Created": 636237737932988392
}
02/26/2017 22:29:53 -08:00 [INF] (IdentityServer3.Core.Endpoints.AuthenticationController)
 rendering login page
02/26/2017 22:30:01 -08:00 [INF] (IdentityServer3.Core.Endpoints.AuthenticationController)
 Login page submitted
02/26/2017 22:30:01 -08:00 [INF] (IdentityServer3.Core.Endpoints.AuthenticationController)
 Login credentials successfully validated by user service
02/26/2017 22:30:01 -08:00 [INF] (IdentityServer3.Core.Endpoints.AuthenticationController)
 Calling PostAuthenticateAsync on the user service
02/26/2017 22:30:01 -08:00 [INF] (IdentityServer3.Core.Endpoints.AuthenticationController)
 issuing primary signin cookie
02/26/2017 22:30:01 -08:00 [INF] (IdentityServer3.Core.Endpoints.AuthenticationController)
 redirecting to: https://mydevserver.example.com:44333/core/wsfed?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=urn:idserver:sp16trial&wctx=https:%2f%2fmysharepointserver.example.com%2f_layouts%2f15%2fAuthenticate.aspx%3fSource%3d%252F
02/26/2017 22:30:01 -08:00 [INF] (IdentityServer3.WsFederation.WsFederationController)
 Start WS-Federation request
02/26/2017 22:30:01 -08:00 [DBG] (IdentityServer3.WsFederation.WsFederationController)
 AbsoluteUri: [https://mydevserver.example.com:44333/core/wsfed?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=urn%3aidserver%3asp16trial&wctx=https%3a%2f%2fmysharepointserver.example.com%2f_layouts%2f15%2fAuthenticate.aspx%3fSource%3d%252F]
02/26/2017 22:30:01 -08:00 [DBG] (IdentityServer3.WsFederation.WsFederationController)
 PublicUri: [https://mydevserver.example.com:44333/core/wsfed?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=urn:idserver:sp16trial&wctx=https:%2f%2fmysharepointserver.example.com%2f_layouts%2f15%2fAuthenticate.aspx%3fSource%3d%252F]
02/26/2017 22:30:01 -08:00 [INF] (IdentityServer3.WsFederation.WsFederationController)
 WsFederation signin request
02/26/2017 22:30:01 -08:00 [INF] (IdentityServer3.WsFederation.Validation.SignInValidator)
 Start WS-Federation signin request validation
02/26/2017 22:30:01 -08:00 [INF] (IdentityServer3.WsFederation.Validation.SignInValidator)
 End WS-Federation signin request validation
{
  "Realm": "urn:idserver:sp16trial",
  "RelyingPartyName": "SharePoint 2016 Trial",
  "ReplyUrl": "https://mysharepointserver.example.com/_trust/"
}
02/26/2017 22:30:01 -08:00 [INF] (IdentityServer3.WsFederation.ResponseHandling.SignInResponseGenerator)
 Creating WS-Federation signin response
02/26/2017 22:30:01 -08:00 [DBG] (IdentityServer3.WsFederation.Hosting.CookieMiddlewareTrackingCookieService)
 Retrieving values of cookie IdSvr.WsFedTracking
02/26/2017 22:30:01 -08:00 [DBG] (IdentityServer3.WsFederation.Hosting.CookieMiddlewareTrackingCookieService)
 Cookie IdSvr.WsFedTracking does not exist
02/26/2017 22:30:01 -08:00 [DBG] (IdentityServer3.WsFederation.Hosting.CookieMiddlewareTrackingCookieService)
 Adding https://mysharepointserver.example.com/_trust/ to IdSvr.WsFedTracking cookie
02/26/2017 22:30:01 -08:00 [DBG] (IdentityServer3.WsFederation.Results.SignInResult)
 Returning WS-Federation signin response
02/26/2017 22:30:02 -08:00 [INF] (IdentityServer3.WsFederation.WsFederationController)
 Start WS-Federation request
02/26/2017 22:30:02 -08:00 [DBG] (IdentityServer3.WsFederation.WsFederationController)
 AbsoluteUri: [https://mydevserver.example.com:44333/core/wsfed?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=urn%3aidserver%3asp16trial&wctx=https%3a%2f%2fmysharepointserver.example.com%2f_layouts%2f15%2fAuthenticate.aspx%3fSource%3d%252F]
02/26/2017 22:30:02 -08:00 [DBG] (IdentityServer3.WsFederation.WsFederationController)
 PublicUri: [https://mydevserver.example.com:44333/core/wsfed?wa=wsignin1.0&wtrealm=urn:idserver:sp16trial&wctx=https:%2f%2fmysharepointserver.example.com%2f_layouts%2f15%2fAuthenticate.aspx%3fSource%3d%252F]
02/26/2017 22:30:02 -08:00 [INF] (IdentityServer3.WsFederation.WsFederationController)
 WsFederation signin request
02/26/2017 22:30:02 -08:00 [INF] (IdentityServer3.WsFederation.Validation.SignInValidator)
 Start WS-Federation signin request validation
02/26/2017 22:30:02 -08:00 [INF] (IdentityServer3.WsFederation.Validation.SignInValidator)
 End WS-Federation signin request validation
{
  "Realm": "urn:idserver:sp16trial",
  "RelyingPartyName": "SharePoint 2016 Trial",
  "ReplyUrl": "https://mysharepointserver.example.com/_trust/"
}
02/26/2017 22:30:02 -08:00 [INF] (IdentityServer3.WsFederation.ResponseHandling.SignInResponseGenerator)
 Creating WS-Federation signin response
02/26/2017 22:30:02 -08:00 [DBG] (IdentityServer3.WsFederation.Hosting.CookieMiddlewareTrackingCookieService)
 Retrieving values of cookie IdSvr.WsFedTracking
02/26/2017 22:30:02 -08:00 [DBG] (IdentityServer3.WsFederation.Hosting.CookieMiddlewareTrackingCookieService)
 https://mysharepointserver.example.com/_trust/ already exists in IdSvr.WsFedTracking cookie
02/26/2017 22:30:02 -08:00 [DBG] (IdentityServer3.WsFederation.Results.SignInResult)
 Returning WS-Federation signin response
02/26/2017 22:30:03 -08:00 [INF] (IdentityServer3.WsFederation.WsFederationController)
 Start WS-Federation request
```

Any idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 3):

You are facing infinite redirects because you are setting the ReplyUrl of your relying party to the trust page and this is not correct.

The ReplyUrl should be the URL that the identity server will redirect to after the login is completed successfully.

This should be the correct logic of your relying party:

> ReplyUrl = "https://mysharepointserver.example.com/"

You need to set the trust URL in the Clients classes:

> RedirectUris = { "https://mysharepointserver.example.com/_trust/" },

Comment: Oh wow, I knew it'd be something painfully obvious! :-)  I won't be able to test this until a while due to other projects, but as soon as I verify it, I'll mark this as answered. Thank you for helping, I had given up hope. :-)

Comment: You are welcome, I also advise you to use Identity server 4 WSFederation as I have experienced another issues related to the trust between SharePoint and 2013, the recent version of identity server supports ASP.NET core, here is a link you can get more information from [Using Identity Server 4 with SharePoint 2013 and WSFederation](https://www.identityserver.com/articles/identityserver4-ws-federation-and-sharepoint/)

Comment: Thank you for the advice and link. Does IdServer4 only support .NET core, or does it REQUIRE it? I'm not working with Core apps yet, so I'd likely need to be able to integrate IdServer with an ASP.NET MVC 4.6.1 app.

Comment: Looking at [Clients.cs](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/blob/master/source/_sharedConfiguration/Clients.cs) I am not sure which client you'd update with `RedirectUris = { "https://mysharepointserver.example.com/_trust/" }`. All of them? Which one(s) get used by Ws-Fed?

Comment: No, not all clients, only the client that has the client id the same as your relying party Realm. if you don't have a client with id as your realm, add a new one and set the redirect url of the the new one properly